# AEM Asset Selector (6.5) and SDL Web 8.5 Integration

Tags: web8.5, media-manager, adobe

We are using Adobe AEM Assets (6.5) as our Media manager and Web 8.5 as our CMS (Dont ask!!! :))

Wondering if anyone used the [Asset selector](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-64/assets/managing/asset-selector.html). What are pro's and con's of this. Please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: I've not used the asset selector specifically but I'm expecting a couple of answers soon enough. Depending on what you want to integrate exactly (and the level of integration) you may be able to work with the connector team and get a 'standard connector' from SDL - if your client is willing.

Comment: Hello Dylan, thank you. Do you mean we need a custom connector? I know for AEM to WS, there is one already. Thus was asking if there is one for CMS

Comment: @Dylan..MarkSaunders, Do we if we have a connector for this from SDL already? I already tried looking at appstore but could not find relevant information.

Comment: @Shiva - nothing that I'm aware of but if you find anything please do ping here/blog :)